How does the wine component pricing model work with cheap wine?
A UK Wine merchant publishes a review of the components of the price of a bottle of wine at different price points, summarised in the image below.  The lowest price they reference is £6.31, apparently "the average price of a 75cl still wine in the UK Off Trade".  Assuming "average" here means mean, then it seems reasonable to assume that the majority of wine sold is cheaper than this (as you cannot get wine for very much less than £6.31, but you can pay a lot more).
From the graph below it is not obvious that there is that much room for cost savings on the price of a £6.31 bottle of wine except perhaps the £1.37 profit, but you can get much cheaper.  For example Lidl sells one at £3.79.
How does the economics work on wine this cheap?  Is it valid to divide up that price in the way bibendum do for this wine?  Can we say where they make the savings compared to the "average" bottle?  Or is this not an appropriate way to look at this sector of the market, with supermarket "loss leaders" and purchasers that can exploit distressed sellers and/or localised overproduction or something such that it does not make sense to talk about the cost of production of the individual product?
I am particularly interested in the UK, as the way duty is calculated is particularly "non-progressive", but answers for other areas could be interesting.


Have you considered that stores may actually be selling things at a loss? Usually done so to encourage foot traffic and increase the overall sales volume. Some also do that for publicity and ideological reason (e.g.: Costco's $4.99 rotisserie chicken), or to get rid of excess stock.

@littleadv Note in the question I mention "loss leaders" and "purchasers that can exploit distressed sellers" which was aimed at saying this is a possibility.

Then... What's your question? This seems like it's going to be closed as off-topic, but even if you post it on the economics@SE stack - it's still not clear what it is that you're actually asking.

@littleadv "What's your question" If that is the answer, or if not what is.

Who knows? It may be the answer for that bottle with that seller. Or not. Price-making is usually a proprietary and secret information that vendors like Lidl won't be happy about sharing on random internet forums.

As the chart you linked shows, the minimum price is actually £3.20 — the excise duty and the VAT on the excise duty. You can always find ways to reduce the costs of packaging, distribution and the wine itself, and of course you can accept a lower margin per bottle in exchange for higher sales.

"You can figure out ways to reduce the cost" Yes that would be the answer; just like the price of wine is given as an average, so too the costs must be listed at an average.
